# Android app Play Core library in App update not working properly

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play-services, in-app-update, google-play-core

I have implemented google play inApp update using play core Play Core library. When a new update is pushed app shows mandatory update notification using this library , downloads new update and shows update complete. But after i exit the app and relaunch it same circle continues. It shows update available please update again notification. I think after download the update is not actually taking place. Please help me with this issue.

```
fun initUpdate() {
        val appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this)
        val appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.appUpdateInfo
        appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener { appUpdateInfo ->
            if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)
            ) {
                appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(appUpdateInfo, AppUpdateType. IMMEDIATE, this, MY_REQUEST_CODE
                )}}}override fun initComponents() {
        initUpdate()
        //rest of the code//
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I got it working after signing the app(with the lower app version to be updated) with production-release KeyStore. I was using a debug keystore to sign it earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code to get the in-app update.

```
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        checkForVersionUpdate()
    }

private fun checkForVersionUpdate() {
        val appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo()
        // Checks that the platform will allow the specified type of update.
        appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener { appUpdateInfo ->
            if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.DEVELOPER_TRIGGERED_UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS) {
                startUpdateFlow(appUpdateInfo)
            } else if ((appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE))) {
                startUpdateFlow(appUpdateInfo)
            }
        }
    }


private fun startUpdateFlow(appUpdateInfo: AppUpdateInfo) {
        try {
            appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                    appUpdateInfo,
                    AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE,
                    this,
                    REQUEST_IMMEDIATE)
        } catch (e: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMMEDIATE && resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            checkForVersionUpdate();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I didn't find the customized popup layout change for the above google-play-core library.